# ¿Como puedo cargar un procedimiento almacenado basado en un xml en asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, xml, stored-procedure

tengo un archivo xml y con otros tutoriales logre cargarlo en una tabla en sql y usar unos procedimientos almacenados para escoger que campos traer, me gustaria saber si existe alguna forma de utilizar el procedimiento en asp.net para que asi vaya a la base de datos y traiga los datos que escogi basados en ese campo con codigo xml

Codigo del xml:

```html
 ROOT>
  <Customers>
    <Customer CustomerName="Arshad Ali" CustomerID="C001">
      <Orders>
        <Order OrderDate="2012-07-04T00:00:00" OrderID="10248">
          <OrderDetail Quantity="5" ProductID="10" />
          <OrderDetail Quantity="12" ProductID="11" />
          <OrderDetail Quantity="10" ProductID="42" />
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Address> Address line 1, 2, 3</Address>
    </Customer>
    <Customer CustomerName="Paul Henriot" CustomerID="C002">
      <Orders>
        <Order OrderDate="2011-07-04T00:00:00" OrderID="10245">
          <OrderDetail Quantity="12" ProductID="11" />
          <OrderDetail Quantity="10" ProductID="42" />
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Address> Address line 5, 6, 7</Address>
    </Customer>
    <Customer CustomerName="Carlos Gonzlez" CustomerID="C003">
      <Orders>
        <Order OrderDate="2012-08-16T00:00:00" OrderID="10283">
          <OrderDetail Quantity="3" ProductID="72" />
        </Order>
      </Orders>
      <Address> Address line 1, 4, 5</Address>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</ROOT>
```

Como lo cargue en sql

```html
CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Juan\Downloads\OpenXMLTesting.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi seria el procedimiento almacenado:

```html
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, Address
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ROOT/Customers/Customer')
WITH 
(
CustomerID [varchar](50) '@CustomerID',
CustomerName [varchar](100) '@CustomerName',
Address [varchar](100) 'Address'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien use el create procedure basico y lo ejecute y funciono. me gustaria lograr cargar ese procedimiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Muchas Gracias :D

Comment: ni modo, ya encontré una forma de hacerlo xD no es tan automático como quería pero creo que puede funciona

Comment: me alegro que encontraras una forma de solucionar el problema. Deberías compartirla con la comunidad por si otro usuario se encuentra con el mismo problema, que pueda servirle de guía. Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información.